# Vitamio Video Center issue

Tags: android, video, aspect-ratio, vitamio

Hi guys I have a video that is not playing in the center of the screen but it is stuck to the left side, How can make the video display in the center nice and neat?, 
For example I want the horse.mp4 file to be centered in the screen and not be played stuck to the left like default

mVideoView.setVideoPath("hprse.mp4");

Answer (score 0):

`<io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView
        android:id="@+id/surface_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />`
To make it center of your parent layout.

Answer (score 0):

[VitamioDemo](https://github.com/yixia/VitamioDemo) has the demo

```
<io.vov.vitamio.widget.CenterLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView
        android:id="@+id/surface_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</io.vov.vitamio.widget.CenterLayout>
```